# Error en mi codigo de Python

Tags: python

Intento hacer un ejercicio que para muchos les parecera "facil" en Python, pero estoy aprendiendo.
El ejercicio es el siguiente:

-Escriba un programa que contenga a la función contar(l, x) que cuente
cuántas veces aparece un carácter l dado en una cadena x.

Tengo errores al momento del testing del codigo.
Este es mi codigo:

```
def contar(l, x):
    l = ""
    x = ""
    count = 0
    for char in x:
        if char == l:
            count += 1
        return count
```

Tengo esta funcion para el testing (uso pytest):

```
def testing():
    assert contar("e", "enciclopedia") == 2
    assert contar("i", "medicina") == 2
    assert contar("a", "anana") == 3
```

Y este es el error al momento del testing:

```
    def testing():
>       assert contar("e", "enciclopedia") == 2
E    AssertionError: assert 0 == 2
E     +  where 0 = contar('e', 'enciclopedia')

strings.py:36: AssertionError
====================================== short test summary info ======================================
FAILED strings.py::testing - AssertionError: assert 0 == 2
========================================= 1 failed in 0.01s =====================================
```

Alguien sabe cual es el error?

Comment: Buen día, estás inicializando `l` y `x` y por lo tanto "borras" los valores que vienen al llamar la función. Por cierto, segun [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) el nombre de variable `l` (L minúscula) no es recomendable porque no se sabe si es L minúscula, "i" mayúscula o 1 y es mejor evitarlo

Comment: Además de que no debes inicializar los parámetros `l` y `x` (ya vienen inicializados con lo que se le pase en la llamada), tienes el `return count` mal colocado. Debería ejecutarse una vez el bucle for haya finalizado pero tal como lo tienes retornaría en la primera iteración

Answer (score 1, accepted):

estas reemplazando tus variables dentro de la función. Además, mueve el `return` al nivel de indentación de la definición. Recuerda que en Python la indentación (tabulación) es importante al crear definiciones, ciclos, clases, etc.

Tu programa quedaría como:

```py
def contar(l, x):
    count = 0

    for char in x:
        if char == l:
            count += 1
        
    return count


def testing():
    assert contar("e", "enciclopedia") == 2
    assert contar("i", "medicina") == 2
    assert contar("a", "anana") == 3
```

Ahora al ejecutar la prueba con pytest se obtiene la verificación correcta: `collected 1 item` `1 passed in 0.03s`

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta:

```
def contar(l, x):
    count = 0
    for char in x:
        if char == l:
            count += 1
    return count
```

`l` y `x` los recibes como parámetros; no debes sobreescribirlos.

El `return` va fuera del `for`. Tal como estaba, la función retorna al encontrar el primer caracter.

También puedes usar la función `count()`:

```
def contar(l, x):
    return x.count(l)
```